# Time complexity of d-dimensional convex hull

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cg.comp-geom, time-complexity, lower-bounds, convex-hull

Consider the convex hull problem in $\Re^d$:

> Input: a list of $n$ points $S$ in $\Re^d$,
>   Output: the vertices of the convex hull of $S$.

What is the best lower bound on the time complexity of the 
$d$-dimensional convex hull problem?

Comment: Lower bounds are dependent on [computational models](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation) one works in not just problems, you should specify in the question the model(s) you are interested in if you have any specific one in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know any nontrivial lower bounds other than the $\Omega(n\log n)$ algebraic-decision-tree lower bound for two dimensions, which also extends to larger $d$.

As for upper bounds: In 3d, the whole hull can be found in $O(n\log n)$; in four or higher dimensions that doesn't work because the hull complexity grows exponentially with $d$, but nevertheless for any fixed $d$, finding all vertices can be done in time $O(n^2)$ (determining whether a given point is a vertex can be done in linear time by solving a linear program), and the Chan reference below improves this slightly.

See

Ottmann and Scheurer, "Enumerating extreme points in higher dimensions", STACS 1995 and Nordic J. Comput. 2001

Chan, "Output-sensitive results on convex hulls, extreme points, and related problems", DCG 1996

Helbling, "Extreme points in medium and high dimensions", ETH thesis 2010

Comment: Doesn't the LP approach show that one can enumerate all the convex hull vertices in fixed polynomial time in any dimension?

Comment: I assume you saw the "for all fixed $d$" part of my answer and that what you mean is that LP gives polynomial time even when $d$ is variable. Maybe, but variable-dimension LP takes time polynomial in (#vars,#constraints,numerical precision of input coordinates) and because of the numerical precision part isn't strongly polynomial. The fixed-dimension results, on the other hand, are strongly polynomial for constant $d$, but with a non-polynomial dependence on $d$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I thought it would be useful to point out the general case even though the LP algorithm is not strongly polynomial. Also the point about hull coplexity growing exponentially with d is somewhat misleading because that is not necessarily relevant here. For instance LP may have a strongly poly time algorithm.